# How to parse the IP and port of the peers from UDP tracker annouce response

Tags: python, bittorrent

I am using this code in python to send connect request and annouce request to udp tracker,

```
clisocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
print clisocket
connection_id = 0x41727101980
transaction_id = randrange(1, 65535)
info_hash = info_hash
peer_id = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
action = 0
downloaded = 0
left = 0
uploaded = 0
event = 2
ip = 0
key = 0
num_want = 10
port = 9999

connect_pack = struct.pack(">QLL", connection_id, action, transaction_id)
clisocket.sendto(connect_pack, ("tracker.publicbt.com", 80))
res = clisocket.recv(16)
action, transaction_id, connection_id = struct.unpack(">LLQ", res)

announce_pack = struct.pack(">QLL20s20sQQQLLLLH", connection_id, 1, transaction_id, info_hash, peer_id, downloaded, left, uploaded, event, ip, key, num_want, port)
clisocket.sendto(announce_pack, ("tracker.publicbt.com", 80))
res = clisocket.recv(1024)
action = struct.unpack("!LLLLLLH", res[:26])
print action
```

I am getting this response,

```
(1, 56347, 1782, 0, 1, 838084381, 9999)
```

as per the protocol specifications [link] : http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html

I am getting 
    annouce i.e 1
    transaction_id i.e 56347 which is same as the generated transaction_id
    but in place of port I am getting the port I am sending in the announce request and in place of IP I am getting 838084381.
    Is this the response that I should get from the udp tracker?
    How to parse the ip of the peers from this?

Comment: How are you sending the info_hash? Perhaps additional parameters are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address is returned in a 32-bit packed format. You can convert it to a dotted-quad string representation like this:

```
import socket, struct    
ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', 838084381))    
print ip; # prints 49.244.39.29
```

[Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_ntoa)

Comment: Thanks xobnez it helped to parse the ip address. But I am not getting other peer ip address from udp tracker. I am getting my own ip address and port. Am I doing anything wrong in the annouce request.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the protocol. Hopefully someone else can come along and help you with that.

Comment: @s.m the message will contain multiple {ip, port} one after the other; just read more than the first 26 bytes